# FGL NodeMap crashes when inserting a node more than once

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to use [`fgl`](http://web.engr.oregonstate.edu/~erwig/fgl/haskell/) as a backend for the tagless-final embedding of the toy EDSL in [this paper](http://okmij.org/ftp/tagless-final/sharing/sharing.html). I'm using the [`NodeMap`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/fgl/5.4.2.4/doc/html/Data-Graph-Inductive-NodeMap.html) interface to build up the DAG described in section 4.2, and am running into an error that can be distilled down to this small example:

```
*ExpFgl> run_ empty ((insMapNodeM 1) >> (insMapNodeM 1)) :: Gr Int ()
*** Exception: Node Exception, Node: 1
```

The way I read the documentation, the first `(insMapNodeM 1)` should succeed, and the second should find 1 already in the `NodeMap` and essentially do nothing. However, I'm getting this exception instead. Am I *doing it wrong*, or is this a bug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The behaviour seems to be undefined, and possibly based upon the behaviour of the underlying `DynGraph` instance.  Can you please try again using `Data.Graph.Inductive.PatriciaTree` and seeing if that works?

Comment: This seems to work, thank you! Do you think this should be reported as a bug, or as just a consequence of the behavior being undefined? It seems like the natural way to use the monadic interface.

Comment: I'm the maintainer of FGL, so I'll have a look.  If you mind, can you please email me with your use-case so I can think about how to improve NodeMap (I've never had a need for it, so I've never really considered it).

Comment: Sure thing, I'll send it along once I work out an orthogonal problem with my algorithm.